# Scrolling to specific element on different template after clicking link (Angularjs)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dom, ui-sref

Hey guys I am pretty new to Angular.

Users can edit profile settings in profileSettings page.

I have the following on my profile template:

```
<div>{{ user.name }}</div>
<a class="pull-right" ui-sref="profileSettings"><strong>Edit Name</strong></a>
...more code...
<div>{{ user.description }}</div>
<a class="pull-right" ui-sref="profileSettings"><strong>Edit Description</strong></a>
```

I want them to be able to click on the edit link that takes them to the  Settingsprofile template. However I want when the new template renders to automatically scroll to the relevant field.

So if they click edit link for name, they are taken to the profileSettings template and automatically scrolled to edit name field. If they click the edit description link then they are also redirected to profileSettings page but automatically scrolled to edit description field.

Is there an easy way to do this with Angualar/ui-sref?

Comment: read the $anchorScroll docs

Comment: I am playing with anchor scroll but keep getting: $location is not defined

Comment: where's the code....we can't guess how you are using it

Answer (score 0):

Use the optional [onEnter](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki#user-content-onenter-and-onexit-callbacks)
callback which will be called when **profileSettings** state becomes active to render those two functions :

- [$location.hash('hashValue')](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$location#hash)
  will take to the element with id="hashValue" *`url like : /profileSettings.html#hashValue`*
- [$anchorScroll](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$anchorScroll)
  will scrolls to that element

So your code may look like this:

```
$stateProvider.state('profileSettings', {
  url: '/settings',
  template: 'settings.html',
  controller: 'ProfileSettingsCtrl',
  onEnter: function(){
      $location.hash('hashValue');
      $anchorScroll();
  }
});
```

**Note:** Remember to add `$location` and `$anchorScroll`to your dependencies.